# Is there a way to read from the bottom of a file until a certain character is found

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, terminal, command-prompt

I am working with a very large file and I need to access the last few entries at the bottom, so using tail would be good, but the problem is the number of lines read changes each time. However, I know I need to stop when a new line character is found so I was wondering if there is a way to do this?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tac` is your friend it is `cat` in reverse

```
tac yourfile|while read LINE; do if [[ -z "$LINE" ]] ;  then break; fi; echo $LINE; done
```

This read the file reverse and stop on first empty line

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, tac file |grep \n still prints the full file and seems to actually remove empty lines. Any suggestions?

Comment: You only want the last line or the two last lines ?

Comment: Reading form the bottom up until a blank line is encountered, the number of lines varies.

Comment: How about `tac filename | sed -n '1,/^$/p'?